# How to fix a fatal error on iOS Application, using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center, xcode7

I made a game using SpriteKit and Xcode 7 beta with swift. I tried to add GameCenter and Leaderboard but the problem is that when I run app (simulator) then when I press on leaderboard button the simulator stops running and It show error on run. I don't know how to fix it. I'm using 2 different files: GameViewController.swift, and PointsLabel.swift

There is an Error in file GameViewController.swift:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on code:

```
@IBAction func leaderboard(sender: UIButton) {
    saveHighscore(score.score) //<- Xcode say Here is Error but error shows on run
    showLeader()
}
```

[image]

GameViewController.swift:

```
import GameKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

var score: PointsLabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //initiate gamecenter
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){

    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(GameViewController, error) -> Void in

        if (GameViewController != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(GameViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            print((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
     }
  }
}

@IBAction func leaderboard(sender: UIButton) {

    saveHighscore(score.score)

    showLeader()

}



//send high score to leaderboard
func saveHighscore(score:Int) {

    //check if user is signed in
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "Leaderboard_01")

        scoreReporter.value = Int64(score)

        let scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {error -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            }
        })
    }
}


    //shows leaderboard screen
    func showLeader() {
        let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
        let gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
        vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//hides leaderboard screen
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController)
{
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

PointsLabel.swift:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class PointsLabel: SKLabelNode {

var score:Int = 0

init(num: Int) {
    super.init()

    fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    fontSize = 30.0

    score = num
    text = "\(num)"
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func increment() {
    score++
    text = "\(score)"
}

func setTo(num: Int) {
    self.score = num
    text = "\(self.score)"
 }
}
```

I hope You can help me because I don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 3):

As I suggested for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167180/how-to-put-gamecenter-on-application-with-swift), start by making the variables names less ambiguous.

The `score` handler object, `var score: PointsLabel!`, should become, for example, `scoreManager`.

Next: I don't see in your example any instanciation of this class. So when you tap your button, you ask for the *implicitly unwrapped* `score` object and its `score` property, but the `score` object doesnt exist.

An actual solution depends on your application logic, I can't provide magic code for you, but try replacing `var score: PointsLabel!` with this:

```
 let scoreManager = PointsLabel(num: 0)
```

Now you have a valid score holder. Then you can use its `score` property:

```
saveHighscore(scoreManager.score)
```

And use its methods to update the score:

```
scoreManager.increment()
```

Etc.

Comment: Now I got You, Thanks bro. Does I need to add anything else because score from app won't add to leaderboard (in leaderboard score stay 0) ? And sorry for many questions, I'm beginner !

Comment: You're welcome. But you already know what I'm going to say: ask a new question. :) This is not to be strict but because on SO we should have only one precise topic for each question.

Comment: Yes, I will try first to fix it by myself, If I can't I will ask another one.

Comment: I find problem, The problem is that I didn't put in right place scoreManager.increment(), I put it in button's function and whenever I pressed leaderboard button the score growed for 1. Can You please edit the question and tell me where to add this "scoreManager.increment()"